# how many input and out put can include to a smart contract as multiple transaction?

Tags: solidity

my main question is that how many addresses I can include to a smart contract as input and output and also I shoud add thease addresses before writing a smart contract or I can adding addresses after writing a smart contract? tnx you for answering

Comment: @LauriPeltonen please answer me

Answer (score 1):

For input, you can take in an array of `address` types. Therefore there is (almost) no limit to how many addresses you can input.

For output, you can do the same: output an array of addresses. Therefore there is also (almost) no limit.

The only limiting factors are the transaction and block maximum sizes, but with just addresses this probably won't be an issue.

As the values are parameters to a function you don't need to define them when deploying the contract.